# Finger Print Scanner Recommendation

Tags: fingerprint-scanner

My office currently uses the Morpho MSO E3 FPS. We use it in rural areas. The device is ok but our agents report that it is not reliable as oil/dirt can disrupt the scan way too easily than it should. Add to that, more often than not, it takes awhile to get a scan. We are looking at new alternatives. Within 40-50$, what FPS should I get. We generally use it with an android device via USB. I am currently looking at the Hamster Pro UPx. Any reviews or suggestions will be extremely helpful.